# Как вызвать в юнит-тесте метод, помеченный @EventListener, с mock-объектом для final поля внутри spring-класса?

Tags: spring, юнит-тесты

Как вызвать в юнит-тесте метод, помеченный @EventListener, с mock-объектом для final поля внутри spring-класса?

В примере

- метод, помеченный @EventListener - public void onRejectEvent(NewEvent
  event)
- mock-объект для final поля внутри spring-класса - private final

  SomeService someService;

  ```
  @Component
  @Slf4j
  @RequiredArgsConstructor
  public class SomeEventListener {
    private final SomeService someService;

    @Async
    @EventListener
    @Transactional
    public void onRejectEvent(NewEvent event) {
      final var someVariable = someService.getSomeVariable();
      // do something
    }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вызвать конструктор, где final-поля передаются в качестве аргументов. Затем спокойно вызывать метод

```
SomeService someService = mock(SomeService.class);
NewEvent event = mock(NewEvent.class);
SomeEventListener someEventListener = new SomeEventListener(someService);
someEventListener.onRejectEvent(event);
```

Answer (score 1):

А зачем вам тестить слушатель? Из слушателя вызывайте методы нужных вам сервисов,  Их работу и тестируйте. Например

```
 @Component
 public class SomeEventListener {

     @Autowired
     private final SomeService someService;

     @Async
     @EventListener
     @Transactional
     public void onRejectEvent(NewEvent event) {
        someService.youMethod();
     }
}


@Service
public class SomeService {

     public void youMethod() {
        ...
     }
}
```

Comment: Методы приватные

Comment: Создайте метод  public, чтоб слушатель мог его дернуть - в нем реализуйте логику

Comment: public не всегда представляется возможным создать